# Unable to use SelectPDF after deployment to IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a function that generates a PDF from a HTML page like this:

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(url);
var PdfArray = doc.Save();
doc.Close();
```

This works perfectly when I run it in VS 2017, However when I deploy to IIS it throws the following exception: "Conversion failure error 5."

According to my Googling this is related to the IIS not having the correct access to write. However I have as an attempt given that application access to every operation.

All suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you publish and which line throw this exception? Have the published folder contains `Select.Html.dep`? If not, copy it from your project.

Comment: It just published to a local IIS server, the published folder is the project folder (so nothing is moved, this might be the reason for it complaining) and yes Select.html.dep is in both the release and debug bin.

Answer (score 0):

From the troubleshooting page on SelectPdf website:
https://selectpdf.com/docs/Troubleshooting.htm#item3

The error code is this:

ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
5 (0x5)
Access is denied.
Enable execute permissions on Select.Html.dep.

You need to go to the bin folder of your deployment to IIS and set execute permissions for the Select.Html.dep file. If you do not know the app pool user, in the first place, just set permissions for Everyone to see if it works.

Comment: The problem remains the same. not able to load the PDF. I have given "All" access to the Select.Html.Dep. In both bin directories.

Comment: What exactly did you do? You need to open an Window Explorer, go to the folder where Select.Html.dep file is, right click on it, then Properties / Security tab and add Everyone full control. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I did. Should I try to restart the machine or something as well?

Comment: Same problem when I run my code from IIS. If I run it on VS or through windows console, it works. Please, help!

Comment: I've realized that when we convert from html to pdf it works on IIS, but when I try to convert it to image through HtmlToImage it hangs on IIS. It seems a bug